# Different Behaviour of GDAL.RasterIo with Python and C++

Tags: python, raster, gdal, c++

I was using GDAL C++ API and Python API to open a tif dataset and read it into memory, but then I got some annoying issue, when I use Python,all works fine.

```
import gdal
ds = gdal.Open('/*.tif')
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
nXsize = band.XSize
data = band.ReadRaster(xoff=0, yoff=0, xsize=nXsize, ysize =1, buf_xsize=nXsize, buf_ysize=1)
```

And the out put is right, nothing happend.

```
data: b'\xe6\x02\xce\x02\xc7\x02\x8e\x02B\x02\xfc\x01\x12\x02\xf5\x01\xd2\x01\xc3\x01\x04\x02\xfc\x01\xc9\x01\x90\x02\xf9\x02\xe4\x02p\x02\x1b\x02\xe8\x01\x02\x02\x00\x0...
```

Then comes C++ API

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <gdal_priv.h>
#include <cpl_conv.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* pszFile;
    GDALAllRegister();
    pszFile = "/*.tif";
    GDALDataset* poDataset = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen(pszFile, GA_ReadOnly);
    GDALRasterBand* poBand = poDataset->GetRasterBand(1);
    float* pafScanline;
    int nXSize = poBand->GetXSize();
        pafScanline = (float*)CPLMalloc(sizeof(float) * nXSize);
    poBand->RasterIO(GF_Read, 0, 0, nXSize, 1,
        pafScanline, nXSize, 1, GDT_Float32,
        0, 0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I comliles the program, nothing happend, then I run it, errors comes out:

```
ERROR 6: Unhandled type for StripOffset/StripByteCount
ERROR 1: /*.tif, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: Unhandled type for StripOffset/StripByteCount
```

The xoff,yoff,Xsize,Ysize parameter are same in two API, why C++ gives me error output?The error said it`IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0`, isn't the xoffset and yoffset start with 0?Hope somebody could answer my question.

Comment: Perhaps the point is in the word "type" in the message `Unhandled type for StripOffset/StripByteCount`.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with the `type` thing, because the same parameters runs perfectly right when the file is a JPG file.@user30184

Comment: It seems that you got a definitive answer through https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2165. Seems so technical that it would have been difficult to resolve the issue by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by the GDAL ticket https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2165.
The problem was indeed in the `type` thing. The BigTIFF file has not been created as the standard requires because StripByteCounts is using signed datatype

```
StripByteCounts (279) SLONG8 (17) 98820<21960 21960...
```

whereas acoording to https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/bigtiff.html only unsigned types (LONG8, LONG, SHORT) are allowed for that tag.

Older GDAL versions did not check the validity of the datatype and your Python trial was obviously done with such old GDAL version.

In the future GDAL will again accept non-conformant BigTIFF through commit https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/5acc54b38bf9bcd45ae8c475f19eb4b8d44ce0bf. It will be included in GDAL 3.1 version that will probably be released around May, 2020.

It would be interesting to know what software was used to create the non-conformant BigTIFF.

Comment: I don't quite remember where this TIF file is from, according to my memory it is original Sentinel-2 JP2, and I use SNAP to transfer it into TIF file; So if I use an older version of GDAL, presumably it will  work?

Comment: According to the GDAL ticket I would guess so. If SNAP creates wrong BigTIFFs it would be very good to catch the error.

Comment: I really don't sure it was SNAP that produces this TIFF,but I use Arcgis transfer that TIFF into another TIFF,and...problem solved.Still, two question comes out, according to you, older version of gdal could accept non-conformant BIGTIFF,but I tired GDAL 2.4.3 with VS2019 on that non-conformant BIGTIFF, things happend same in GDAL 3.0.2; Second, I still don't why I could use Python to correctly reading that non-conformant BIGTIFF, I'm pretty sure I was using the same gdal 3.0.2.@user30184

Comment: Then I suggest to continue the discussion with the GDAL developer. I believe that comment to ticket will be read even it is already closed.

Comment: The 2.4 line of GDAL is still maintained and may contain the same changes. If you are still interested you could have a try by using some clearly older version from http://gisinternals.com/archive.php.

Comment: For now,my issue has been solved by using`Arcgis`transfer the TIFF into another TIFF,though I don't know what happend in this process to eliminate the problem;Right now I am more interested in Python API's different behaviour.Thanks anyway@user30184.